# Хостинг и загрузка сайта на сервер

Tags: сервер, хостинг, hosting

Собрался загрузить свой маленький простенький сайт на бесплатный хостинг с поддержкой PHP, написано, что все файлы должны храниться в корневом каталоге  **public_html**, а как должна называться главная страница ? **Index.php** ? Или как ? Там по умолчанию лежит страница с названием **Default.php**

Comment: Загружаете все файлы в public_html. Главная страница - index.php, верно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Главная страница - index.php или index.html (если страница статична)